# VS 2017 won't find DirectX include files

Tags: c++, directx, visual-studio-2017, directx-9

I have installed the DirectX SDK and I want to use in my C++ project in Visual Studio 2017. I configured the C++ include path and added a directory with the DirectX SDK include files (`$(DXSDK_DIR)Include\`) which resolves correctly to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\` where all the files are located
But when I try to `#include <d3dx9core.h>` which, as I checked myself, is correctly installed in the `Include` directory, it says it can't find the file.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to deal with deprecated DirectX9? Modern DirectX SDK is part of Windows SDK and there is also [DirectX Toolkit auxiliary library](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK).

Comment: @VTT Yes, DirectX9 is a requirement.

Comment: Do you have 1 project in your solution? Did you set include path for all Platform/Configuration combinations?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky No, there are multiple projects in my solution, but this is the only one that uses it and yes, I've set it for all combinations.

Comment: Try the following - Goto `Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run` and set build output verbosity to Diagnostics. Then compile only one cpp file that includes `<d3dx9core.h>` and check the output. You will see all environment variables settings and `IncludePath =` that is actually used to compile this file. See if the DX folder is properly added to this entry. Maybe it is combined with next path...

Comment: Check build option is match to your project options , Also use `" "` for local files instead of `< >`

Comment: *Why* do you feel that DirectX 9 specifically is a requirement? DirectX 11 is a much better choice in almost all cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use the legacy DirectX SDK with VS 2010 or later, you have to manually add references to the include/lib paths. This is typically done by editing the *VC++ Directories* settings for your project putting the DirectX SDK folders first.

To use the legacy DirectX SDK with VS 2012 or later, you need use the *reverse* the path order--list the DirectX SDK folders after the standard ones--because Windows 8.x / Windows 10 SDK contains *newer* headers than the legacy DirectX SDK. Of course, there's no newer version of the D3DX9 headers.

For x86/Win32 configurations:

```
$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86
```

For x64 native configurations:

```
$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x64;$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64
```

There are also a few known issues when doing this that are addressed on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-). For example, you should explicitly include `d3d9.h` before you include `d3dx9.h` because otherwise you'll end up with the older `d3d9.h` header.

BTW, the `dxerr.lib` static libraries are not compatible with the VS 2015/VS 2017 C/C++ Runtime. [Where’s DXERR.LIB?](https://walbourn.github.io/wheres-dxerr-lib/)

One last gotcha: Direct3D 9 Debug Device is not supported on Windows 8.x or Windows 10.

> Be sure to see [Where is the DirectX SDK](https://walbourn.github.io/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/), [Not So DirectSetup](https://walbourn.github.io/not-so-direct-setup/), and [DXSETUP Update](https://walbourn.github.io/dxsetup-update/)
>
> You should also review [Living without D3DX](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/), [DirectX SDK Tools Catalog](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-sdk-tools-catalog/), [DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-sdk-samples-catalog/) and [The Zombie DirectX SDK](https://walbourn.github.io/the-zombie-directx-sdk/)