# Adding directx to include and library directories throws over 300 errors

Tags: visual-studio, dll, directx, directx-9, directx-10

Im trying to work with direct x 9 / 10 right now but as soon as I add

```
C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft DirectX SDK %28November 2008%29\Include
```

to my include directory and

```
C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft DirectX SDK %28November 2008%29\Lib\x86
```

to my library directories

I get 397 errors mostly consisting of

```
identifier "__RPC__inout_xcount" is undefined
```

and

```
expected a ')'  solution    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\OAIdl.h  5621
```

I don't understand what's causing all these errors in dlls I never touched which is located in a folder which I haven't seen before. Any help is appreciated

Comment: There's some include mismatch. Make sure you don't remove default includes, and just "add" your new includes after defaults. Try to add windows.h before anything else in your source. Check this out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a47e4fe8-7b3f-45fc-83ee-6bd225213eb9/error-c2061-while-compiling-with-windows-7sdk?forum=windowssdk otherwise put your project on the internet so we can check it.

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue is that you have to reverse the include/lib path search order to use the legacy DirectX SDK in combination with the Windows 10 SDK.

For x86/Win32 configurations:

```
$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86
```

For x64 native configurations:

```
$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x64;$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64
```

Alternatively, you need to use the `v14?_xp` Platform Toolset which uses the Windows 7.1A SDK instead.

> The legacy DirectX SDK was designed to work with the Windows 7 SDK or earlier that came with VS 2010, and the DirectX SDK is now deprecated.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) and [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/visual-studio-2012-update-1/).

A better option is to not use the legacy DirectX SDK at all, which means using DirectX 11 instead of the older DX9/DX10 APIs. See [Living without D3DX](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/).

There are also various StackOverflow threads that are all the same basic issue:

- [VS 2017 won't find DirectX include files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46755321/vs-2017-wont-find-directx-include-files)

> Be sure to read [Where is the DirectX SDK (2021 Edition)?](https://walbourn.github.io/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2021-edition/)